# How to put line breaks in the labels of the table output by gt_regression() and output it by LaTeX?

Tags: r, gtsummary

According to [the documentation of the gtsummay package](https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/add_significance_stars.html#examples), you can use `<br>` in `add_significance_stars()` to break the labels of the table showing the results of the regression model in HTML, but it does not work for LaTeX.
I have tried other line break methods such as `\n`, but it still does not work. How can I make line breaks in LaTeX?

Here is an example in HTML.

```
df <- 
mtcars %>% 
  lm(mpg ~ ., data = .)

df %>%
  tbl_regression() %>%
  add_significance_stars(
    hide_se = TRUE,
    pattern = "{estimate}{stars}<br>({std.error})"
  ) %>%
  modify_header(estimate ~ "OLS<br>result")
```

And here is a LaTeX example.

```
df %>% 
  tbl_regression() %>% 
  add_significance_stars(
    hide_se = TRUE,
    pattern = "{estimate}{stars}<br>({std.error})"
  ) %>%
  modify_header(estimate ~ "OLS<br>result") %>% 
  as_kable_extra(
    format = "latex",
    booktabs = TRUE
    )
```

I created a table based on the answer, but I found that this method causes the layout to be broken when using `tbl_merge()`.

I will present the problem code again.

```
# make nested dataframe
nest_df <- 
mtcars %>% 
  tibble() %>% 
  group_nest(vs)

# make function
mod_fun <- function(df){lm(mpg ~ ., data = df)}

# map function
nest_df <-
  nest_df %>% 
  mutate(model = map(data, mod_fun))

# make table
nest_df <- 
  nest_df %>%
  mutate(
    tbl = map(
      .x = model,
      ~ tbl_regression(
        .x,
      ) %>% 
        add_significance_stars(
          hide_se = TRUE,
          pattern = "{estimate}{stars}\\\\&({std.error})"
        ) %>%
        modify_header(estimate ~ "OLS\\\\&result")
    )
  )

# merge table
nest_df_m <- 
  tbl_merge(
    tbls = nest_df$tbl,
    tab_spanner = c("type1", "type2")
  )

# output merged table
nest_df_m  %>%
  as_kable_extra(
    format = "latex",
    booktabs = TRUE,
    escape = FALSE
    ) %>% 
  kable_styling(position = "center")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this fits your need. You could a line break by

1. adding `\\\\` (which gives an `\\` in the latex code),
2. adding an `&` to put the `std.error` in the same column as the estimate,
3. setting `escape=FALSE` in `as_kable_extra`.

```
    df %>% 
      tbl_regression() %>% 
      add_significance_stars(
        hide_se = TRUE,
        pattern = "{estimate}{stars}\\\\&({std.error})"
      ) %>%
      modify_header(estimate ~ "OLS\\\\&result") %>% 
      as_kable_extra(
        format = "latex",
        booktabs = TRUE,
        escape = FALSE
      )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was able to reproduce the result. But I still have a problem. Actually, the real data is more complicated, and I run OLS for each different group. But with the above method, the layout seems to be broken when I use `tbl_merge()`.
I will edit the question.